# Yeoman module ngAnimate missing when building application

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, bower, yeoman, ng-animate

I'm building an application with AngularJs and Yeoman and when I do "$ grunt serve" my website runs with no problems but when i do "$ grunt build" i get the following error

**It Seems that even an empty Yeoman project goes belly up when changing bootstrap v3 to v4!**

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyWebApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngAnimate due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngAnimate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "mywebapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "v4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-google-maps": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "MyWebApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

this is the top of my app.js:

```
angular.module('MyWebApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
    'MyWebApp.config'
  ])...
```

This is the scripts section of the index.html

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-simple-logger/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
        <script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/navbar.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: let's start with the obvious things first, it's very likely these are not the issues but it's better to check: Do you have the .js file included in your index.html? If there is, is it after or before the js containing your module?

Comment: updated the post with the script section of the index.html

Comment: maybe try bower uninstall angular-animate --save and then bower install angular-animate --save to reinstall?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the content of your .tmp directory? sometimes "grunt build" keeps checking files in that folder

Comment: Nope both solutions didn't work, strange thing is when i uncomment ngAnimate the error shifts to ngCookies

Comment: Edited the post with: **It Seems that even an empty Yeoman project goes belly up when changing bootstrap v3 to v4!**

Comment: have you tried running grunt build --verbose and grunt build --debug? I find it weird that the error is just about angular modules, i think it's a side effect of something else. Also shouldn't bootstrap 4 be in sass rather than less?